# In Order to Call an API for Current Weather for a Particular City, How Do I Find a City ID from "city.list.json.gz"?

Tags: json, web-applications, sublimetext3, api-design

I'm using [openweathermap.org](http://openweathermap.org/appid) to enable me to create the API call to get my weather app to work, but I'm having total trouble trying to find the ID for my city from the information giving at [openweathermap.org](http://openweathermap.org/appid), which says, "**Call API by city ID instead of city name, city coordinates or zip code. In this case you get precise respond exactly for your city. The cities' IDs can be found in the following file: [Cities' IDs list](http://bulk.openweathermap.org/sample/city.list.json.gz).**

Clicking on that link causes a file named **city.list.json.gz** to be  automatically downloaded. When I open this file with my Sublime3 Text editor, all I get is huge list of columns of numbers that look like this:

```
1f8b 0808 30a1 f458 0003 6369 7479 2e6c
6973 742e 6a73 6f6e 00ac bd4b 6f24 5996
1eb8 9f5f e1e8 8d5a 40d3 e7be 1fb3 2319
afcc 78b1 82cc 0865 ceea 92b4 a05b d069
c632 7763 1443 10d0 d5c0 60a0 4563 b66a
6dba f500 a673 0a02 4668 4168 48da 3173
377f a2fb 97cc 39e6 9111 5976 0eef b536
2a0a 1999 e589 48ff 78ef b9e7 7dbe f3bf
ff2f 8bc5 bf84 bf16 8b3f a9cf ffe4 7f5b
78e1 8313 7fb6 fba4 4957 157c f627 cffa
..........................................
```

Where do I find my city ID in this? Or is my editor not the appropriate software to open this file with?

Comment: based on the .gz extension i guess the file is compressed, try decompressing it, that should give you a .json file, which i assume will have the info youre looking for.

Comment: gz is a compressed file, similar to a ZIP file but a different format. Open it using a program which can read these types of files (e.g. 7-zip if you're on Windows is one such program) and then extract the actual file.

Comment: @BrianH. I already decompressed it....to a JSON file. But I don't think the software that I was using, Sublime Text 3, can open it. I think I'm going to try using the JSON Google Chrome extension while on the openweathermap.org website.

Comment: @ADyson, I'm going to try to see if I can get 7-zip for free....

Comment: @ADyson, thanks!!!! 7-Zip worked like a charm! I extracted the file using 7-Zip, which outputted it as a JSON file, then I opened it with my Sublime text editor and BAM! It worked!!!

Comment: @codebwoy no worries. .gz (and .tar.gz) are pretty common file formats for compressed data in the Unix/Linux/Mac worlds, but not so much in Windows, where .zip seems to be pretty much the only player. Therefore if you're mainly a Windows user it's perhaps not something you'd come across very often. But the principle is identical - get a file or file(s), wrap it up in a compressed file and distribute it, just as the openweathermap people have done with their JSON file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try, please, another programm to open it. I' ve opened this file by Windows10 Code Writer app and see json data like

```
{
    "id": 707860,
    "name": "Hurzuf",
    "country": "UA",
    "coord": {
      "lon": 34.283333,
      "lat": 44.549999
    }
  },
```

and so on

Comment: I have Windows 8....and the Code Writer app for Windows 8 unfortunately can't open JSON files....

Comment: I just tried another program 7-Zip..it worked perfect....same output as you showed in the above example!